# Can C++ close a '''fstream''' variable after '''.close()'''?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Suppose there is a code below:

```
ifstream in("in.txt", ios::in | ios::binary)
ofstream out("out.txt", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);

if(in.is_open() && out.is_open())
{
    //TODO
}
else
{
    cout << "\nUnable to open file. Error!!\n";
}

in.close();
out.close();
```

After operation above, can I delete `in` and `out` during program processing?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but  you only delete something that was from a new. Just like if you declare something `MyType x;` you can't or shouldn't delete it. It goes away when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Please *show* what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question body does not match your question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure i understand the question correctly but you don't need to delete anything, especially if this code is inside a function, you close the streams like you already do and when the function ends you're good to go.

Comment: In fact, if the stream object is going out of scope you don't need to `.close()` it at all, as that will be done automatically by the destructor. Perfectly safe to do it anyway if you really want to, but it's a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

The streams will be closed and deleted when they go out of scope:

```
{
    ifstream in("in.txt", ios::in | ios::binary)
    ofstream out("out.txt", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);

    if(in && out)
    {
        //TODO
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nUnable to open file. Error!!\n";
    }
} // no close needed and no delete should be done
```